# How to write tests for typescript typing definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

We have a Node.js lib, recently we added a type definitions for it.

But how could I test the type definition?

Comment: I just found it and haven't had a chance to really evaluate it, but with all those caveats: https://github.com/mmkal/expect-type. It is supposed to let you make jest assertions about types.  If I get around to testing it, I might even write a proper response.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's [`dtslint`](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint) is a handy tool for testing type declarations. As the name suggests its a static analysis tool that doesn't run your test files but only type-checks them. You can additionally supplement tests with comment-based assertions that the tool evaluates:

```js
import { f } from "my-lib"; // f is(n: number) => void

// $ExpectType void
f(1);

// Can also write the assertion on the same line.
f(2); // $ExpectType void

// $ExpectError
f("one");
```

[`tsd`](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd) is another tool with similar assertions:

```js
import {expectType} from 'tsd';
import concat from '.';

expectType<string>(concat('foo', 'bar'));
expectType<string>(concat(1, 2));
```

Also as of Typescript 3.9 you can use the built-in `// @ts-expect-error` comment:

> When a line is prefixed with a // @ts-expect-error comment, TypeScript will suppress that error from being reported; but if there’s no error, TypeScript will report that // @ts-expect-error wasn’t necessary. ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9/#ts-expect-error-comments))

Comment: `// @ts-expect-error` is exactly what I was looking for when I found this question!

Comment: Me too! I can't believe how simple & useful `// @ts-expect-error` is! I was fiddling with `typings.failing-tests.ts-ignore.ts` where `**/*ts-ignore*` would be ignored in `tsconfig`, but this is way more flexible & useful! 

The problem with it though, is I can't see what the error is. It matters a lot, to see if my typings design is solid...! I would like to some how assert the error, which is very hard to even think about! This is a good read https://dev.to/oliverjumpertz/making-good-use-of-ts-expect-error-in-typescript-1f41

Comment: Ok, I found this workflow hack: In your `typings-failing-tests` test file, you replace it with a `// @DISABLED-ts-expect-error` while developing typings in general, and you want to examine the errors produced by your bad-example tests. When done you replace it back to `// @ts-expect-error`, the way it should be when you check it in. If something breaks you will know. But if you want to investigate the errors you replace it back ;-) While at it, rename your file to `typings-failing-tests.ts-NOT-ignore.prettier-ignore` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The tests in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) are files that are supposed to type-check correctly. So the test exercises different parts of the API, and it's run through the compiler (but the generated JavaScript code is not actually executed). See, for example, tests for [@types/express](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/express-tests.ts).

For your own project, I guess you'd write a similar test file yourself, and compile it as part of your build (if it compiles, then the test succeeds). Of course, if you already have existing TypeScript code using those type definitions, that might be sufficient test.

[Typings-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings-checker) is a proof-of-concept that also allows testing failures (incorrectly typed code should not compile).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a lib for this purpose, check it out: https://github.com/qurhub/qur-typetest

The typescript compiler only checks that types are correct, but it is not capable of checking whether your type fails when you expect it to fail.

So, in the mentioned library you write tests like this:

```
const str: string = "foo"
```

in order to ensure type `string` compiles when assigned to value `"foo"`. And you write tests like this:

```
// tt:throws:Type '1' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const str: string = 1
```

in order to ensure type `string` fails to compile when assigned to value `1`.

Of course, instead of `string` you should test your actual complex types, like, for example, mapped types.

Answer (score 1):

An option if one is only checking types is to use syntax highlighting.  In a test file I do something like this:

```
const t=(result:true)=>console.log(result)
const f=(result:false)=>console.log(result)

type MyType = string

t(false as ( 'dog' extends MyType ? true : false ))
t(false as ( 1 extends MyType ? true : false ))
f(true as ( 1 extends MyType ? true : false ))

let x : 'a' | 'b'

t(false as ( 'a' extends typeof x ? true : false ))
t(false as ( 'b' extends typeof x ? true : false ))
t(false as ( 'c' extends typeof x ? true : false ))
```

[code with syntax highlight](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFC8AKATgUwgVwDZQFxWQ1QEp4A+USELVAOixAHMV1spiAoS6GAMyTSYcuXgEMsEEuW7U6DZoLacOUAJ4AHVDACyqgCoat8GNGQBLMIw4rEYiVtEQYiGAHIAJk1cxUADyioYO5OugaaMAD8cIRauHzikjDEnFC2CQ5OLgCMPv6BwTr6hpHRRDBxdonJHLyIBGWOzjA5fgFBIUXhUfWx8fZJyjSwvuVuot4APm4ARq7WqZUZTa7juW0FapogvDAj3TGjiwM2R40urrNr+U6bqNu7JT2H6ccLL2duwN6t13CG93tSr0jtUgA)

The structure is: `t(false as ( <<<test>>> extends <<<type to test>>> ? true ; false ))`