# Make sure type constraint works as intended without regressions

Tags: typescript

Say I have a complex type, it requires many nested generic and conditional types.

Once I get it right, how can I guard that I don't break it if it ever get's refactored?

To Illustrate this, let's examine an imaginary (but simple) example:

Let's say for example, I have an imaginary type called `PrimeNumber`

And so I create an interface like so:

```
interface Primes {
  [k: string]: PrimeNumber
}
```

Now I expect this to be valid code:

```
const myPrimes:Primes = { small: 2, big: 7919, favorite: 7 }
```

And I would expect this to not be valid:

```
const notReallyPrimes:Primes = { score: 10 } // 10 is not prime
```

Now I can manually put that last example in my editor and see that it causes a compilation error.

However I cannot put that code in a unit test for the very fact that *it causes a compilation error.*

So any time I touch any of the code in the definition of `PrimeNumber` I do not know if I broke it, what if I accidentally made it work for all numbers? Nothing would tell me otherwise. I would get no compilation error because all prime numbers are still numbers meaning all my existing code still adheres and I would quietly break my type.

The only way to know that I did not break my type (that I know of) is to put a ton of examples in my editor, and manually verify that the ones I expect to be good are, and the ones I expect to not be good, cause compilation errors. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Have you checked this question [How to write tests for typescript typing definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296151/how-to-write-tests-for-typescript-typing-definition)? If you will follow the links further, you can find libraries like [tsd](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd) where there is an utility like **expectNotAssignable** or **expectNotType**. I imagine you can write something along `expectNotType<Primes>({score:10})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript 3.9 introduces special syntax to solve this exact use case:

`// @ts-expect-error`

Put that comment above the line that should cause a type error. Now TypeScript will throw an error if the line *doesn't* cause an error! Pretty nifty. A full explanation is in the TS 3.9 blog post: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments